# Firestore, Give permission to read the document created by the one user to others

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the firestore and want to apply the security rule for showing the document to the particular users to my document. Like i have created the Document D1 and want to give access to Users U1, U4, U8 and U334 to read. i.e. the document D1 will only be visible to these users only. I am unable to get any reference or help over this.

Comment: Check out this docs page, hope this helps:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with security permissions in your scenario just apply the basic security rules and then

First of all authenticate all the users then maintain each user created documents and their records in each user document.

Reading someone else's document can be controlled programatically so in each user document this information should be kept that user has access to which document.

Hope you get something.

Comment: Thanks @Nouman, this gives an idea. Also JRLtechwriting link is what i am looking for.